Using VueFire with Firebase Emulators
I can't figure out how to properly use VueFire to authenticate my Vue App against a local Firebase Emulator. It works great for the Firestore Emulator, but the Auth escapes me. Anyone have any suggestion on my configuration or usage?
In my firebase.json:
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./dist",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 9099
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5002
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}


In my main.ts:
app.use(VueFire, {
  firebaseApp,
  modules: [VueFireAuth()]
})

In my firebase.ts based on my firebase config, removing my keys here:
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'my api key',
  authDomain: 'xxxxx.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'xxxxx',
  appId: 'my app id'
}
export const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

And lastly, the script part of my SignUpPage.vue:
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useFirebaseAuth } from 'vuefire'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from '@firebase/auth'

import BaseButton from '@/components/base/BaseButton.vue'
import BaseContainer from '@/components/base/BaseContainer.vue'
import BaseCard from '@/components/base/BaseCard.vue'
import BaseForm from '@/components/base/BaseForm.vue'
import BaseInput from '@/components/base/BaseInput.vue'

const newUser = ref({
  email: '',
  password: ''
})

const auth = useFirebaseAuth()

async function createUser() {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUser.value.email, newUser.value.password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in
      const user = userCredential.user
      console.log(user)
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code
      const errorMessage = error.message
      console.log(`${errorCode}: ${errorMessage}`)
    })
}
</script>

For information, I am using Vite as a server, but I used "firebase init hosting" which detected the Vite setup. I changed firebase.json to point public to "./dist" and firestore works like a charm.
Current result:
Firestore points to my emulator correctly.
But any authentication points to my production server instead of my emulator.
Thanks for any pointers!
EDIT
I believe I have fixed this problem. The problem looked like it was Vite and which MODE was being used - BUT it works much simpler than that.
I basically used the experimental features available (risks understood) and followed the excellent video by David East:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-CS73eHld0
My firebase.ts now looks like this:
import { initializeApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

function initialize(existingApp) {
  const firebaseApp = existingApp || initializeApp()
  const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
  return { firebaseApp, auth }
}

export function getFirebase() {
  const existingApp = getApps().at(0)
  return initialize(existingApp)
}

Thank you David East!
